# Can I ask this type of questions

Tags: support, acceptable-questions

I have a view on a certain topic that I relate to an anime. Can I say my view and ask people to give their perceptions and points on the truth or shortcomings of my view

Comment: Can you provide an example so we understand better the scope of thiis type of questions? Anyway, you can ask for confirmation of your point of you if your point is relevant enough, I guess

Comment: If you're looking for a discussion, it would not be acceptable for the main site. But you can join our chat and talk about anything there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as that would be [too opinion-based](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to be a valid question on Anime & Manga.

You can however, since you have over 20 reputation points, start these discussions in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697).